# Get a product by variants.price using fetchQuery - Shopify JS Buy SDK

Tags: shopify

```
const query = {
    query: 'variants.price:="82.00"',
    sortBy: 'title'
};
client.product.fetchQuery(query).then((products) => {
    console.log(products);
})
```

Is it possible to fetch a product by targeting a field inside variants array? Example: Show me products having variants.price = 82.00?

Answer (score 0):

I kind of got the solution. It still doesn't solve my exact use case, however, it's close.

```
const query = {
    query: "variant:['price: 82.00']"
};
client.product.fetchQuery(query).then((products) => {
    console.log(products); 

})
```

Now, what basically happened here is that I received the `product` that had a variant whose price was `82.00`. What I was looking for is to only get the `variant` that had the price of `82.00` along with the product.
This is because may be the `variant` isn't mapped as a field type = nested.

Shopify internally uses elasticsearch. Hence, the mechanism is similar.